# How to set up apache vhosts for .phar file web application

Tags: php, apache, vhosts

I have `.phar` file (**project.phar**) of one of my web application build in `PHP ZF2` .

I just want to setup `vhosts` to run this application how to do that i can file any  tutorials on internet

Answer (score 0):

```
 /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf
```

contains

```
 <FilesMatch "\.ph(ar|p3?|tml)$">
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
 </FilesMatch>
```

[more info](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=639268)